# One domain, two hosts, multiple subdomains on second host

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, hosting, subdomain

So here's the deal:

- 1 domain (example.com)
- 2 shared hosting plans (for each, all domains and subdomains have the same IP address)

I've already set up **sub1.example.com** to point to the IP (using A) of the second host and it works.

Now what if I want to point **sub2.example.com** to the same host, but different folder? I can't point to the same IP. Is there a way around it? Or do I have to get dedicated IPs for each subdomain on the second host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS translates hostnames to IPs, there is no such thing as a different folder DNS-wise.
The translation hostname (or more generally: URL) to folder must be done in your webserver configuration. This is called virtual hosting. (Some problems arise if you need https for several names)

Answer (score 1):

if you use Apache as a webserver, you have to create different `<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:80>` configs and direct them into a folder with `DocumentRoot /var/www/sub2`. Check out `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default` on a linux server and most probably `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you cannot point 1000 domains to 1 IP, you just need to configure your web/mail/whatever server to respond to each domain..